# Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart

im getting these errors and dont know how to fix them.

```
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:269:14: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'.
 - 'PlatformButton' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
      return FlatButton(
             ^^^^^^^^^^

../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:302:12: Error: The method 'RaisedButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'.
 - 'PlatformButton' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'RaisedButton'.
    return RaisedButton(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^

../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_dialog_action.dart:171:14: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformDialogAction'.
 - 'PlatformDialogAction' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_dialog_action.dart' ('../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_dialog_action.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
      return FlatButton(
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 24):

If you're on the latest version of Flutter, `Flatbutton` is deprecated, use `TextButton` instead. You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context)

Comment: This error points out to none, How do we know where the Flat Button is being used in the project?

Comment: @TechnicalRadar just use the find function

Answer (score 15):

```
**Old Widget        change to    New Widget      
FlatButton   =>      TextButton      
RaisedButton =>      ElevatedButton  
OutlineButton =>    OutlinedButton**
```

for more details...
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context

Comment: Does it mean you have to change them in every document of the project manual, or is there a simpler way.

Answer (score 6):

**FlatButton** is deprecated and  totally removed from flutter after flutter 2.1.0
Use ***TextButton*** instead of **FlatButton** as follows:

```
TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Gradient'),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen from Flutter Documentation:
[image]

Old Widgets have been removed, Now you have to use the new widget along with the new theme. Here is a quick [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context) on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the last package you added in pubspec.yaml and delete it and see if no error occurs then the error is because the package

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the velocity_x:old version to new version.
For Eg:
in pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
velocity_x:^1.4.1 change it to ^3.2.1