# How to fix FlatButton and RaiseButton Error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, deprecated

Please i don't explicitly use RaiseButton or FlatButton in my code. But i get this error

```
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:269:14: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'.
 - 'PlatformButton' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
      return FlatButton(
             ^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:302:12: Error: The method 'RaisedButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'.
 - 'PlatformButton' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'RaisedButton'.
    return RaisedButton(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thank for help

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73737240/error-the-method-flatbutton-isnt-defined-for-the-class-platformbutton)  who did not work for me.

Comment: I've reopened the question 8 min ago :)

Comment: @eamirho3ein I think that it is 'flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart' dependency who come with RaisedButton and FlatButton. And i didn't explicitly install 'flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0' so it should depend on another package.

Answer (score 0):

flutter_platform_widgets used those deprecated widgets. If you update it to 2.0.0 problem will be fixed

[flutter_platform_widgets/changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets/changelog)

Comment: I didn't use any `RaisedButton` or `FlatButton` in my code source. I think that it is `flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart` dependency who come with `RaisedButton` and `FlatButton`. But i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for all the deprecated answers then. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter > 2.0, RaisedButton widget is deprecated and replaced by ElevatedButton widget. One example usage of ElevatedButton is mentioned here

For more info, check the official docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version of `flutter_platform_widgets` and in that version, package use `RaisedButton` and `FlatButton` which are deprecated, so try updated your package to newer version like: `flutter_platform_widgets: ^2.0.0` .

If you not used flutter_platform_widgets directly, you need to search in all your packages and check which package use flutter_platform_widgets and try to updated that.

Comment: yes thanks. i'm going to do that

Comment: it was package `enough_giphy_flutter` and it's the latest version I was already using (0.3.0). What alternative now ?

Comment: you can replace this package with some other package, try not use those package which has long time pass from its last update.

Comment: you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/giphy_get/versions)

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use **RaisedButton** or **FlatButton** in the latest versions they are deprecated. Use **ElevatedButton** instead.